# Home wifi network can't reach Microsoft login sites

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I've got an AmpliFi Router HD wifi router. Nothing connected through the wifi can reach the Microsoft login page. For example, if I'm on my cell phone and I try to access a Microsoft resource (outlook.com or the OneDrive app, for example), it will fail every time. I have to turn off wifi, perform the login over the cellphone network, and then I can reenable wifi and things work fine until the credentials expire. Then I have to repeat the process all over again.

Machines connected to the ethernet work just fine (including one machine that is plugged into the AmpliFi router).

I'm not necessarily asking for someone to diagnose my network (although if there's a magic "make it work with Microsoft" button, please let me know ), but I'd appreciate some pointers on how to figure out what's going wrong on my own.

Comment: Set or Reset the DNS settings in the wireless config. Also make sure Wireless Isolation (if you have that) is OFF.

Comment: Well holy crap. I changed the primary DNS (I didn't recognize what was there) to CloudFlare's 1.1.1.1 free DNS, and now it appears to work fine. Thanks so much, this has been a pain for waaaaay longer than I want to admit. 

Comment: I posted an answer for you and hopefully you wish acknowledge it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Home wifi network can't reach Microsoft login sites   ....    Machines
> connected to the ethernet work just fine

Set or Reset the DNS settings in the wireless config.

You may also wish to make sure Wireless Isolation (if you have that) is OFF. –